# Missing Standard Report

Tags: reporting, campaign

I inherited an org and the previous admin did a lot of customization to reports with regards to contacts and leads.

At this point I can't find the standard report for Campaign Contacts. I've done some research and there doesn't seem to be any way to hide it. I have checked the org wide defaults and standard reports are enabled. I am the system admin with full access and checked that I am in fact a marketing user.

I have a custom report for contacts, but I need to have access to the "Add to Campaign" button.

Where could the standard report be?

Comment: Every reporting checkbox in my profile is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't remember that you can hide reports by checking the "Select Report Types to Hide" box at report creation.